# Concatenating using string literals in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string-concatenation, string-literals

I'm trying to understand how concatenation with string literals. I'm trying to take values from objects and add them to strings.

```js
let obj = {
  name: 'Mitch',
  age: 29,
  job: 'tutor'
};

function createSentence(obj) { // return a string from obj    
  const result = ''
  result = `Hello my name is ${name}, I am ${age} years old and I am a ${job}`;
  return result;

}
console.log(result);
```

The error that I'm getting is that my result object is not defined. I thought I can assign its new value at the same time as I do the declaration. I tried adding a new line just for declaring the result as an empty string, but that doesn't change anything.

Comment: 2 issues, `name` and others wont destructure from obj, do `function createSentence({name, age, job})` second is you cant redefine a `const`, use let instead or simply just return, you don't need to assign result

Comment: You never call the function, the `console.log` is outside of the function, and you never declared the variables `name`/`age`/`job` anywhere

Comment: ^ correction 3 issues

Comment: You should also learn about scope in Javascript. Just learn Javascript

Comment: Also, `result` is only declared inside the function, not outside of it. Hence the error that. But also what LawrenceCherone and Bergi said - you never call the function + you'd have errors if you do.

Comment: technically if there was no `const result = ''`, the next line would be mutating a global `result` variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let obj = {
  name: 'Mitch',
  age: 29,
  job: 'tutor'
};

function createSentence(obj) { // return a string from obj    
  return `Hello my name is ${obj.name}, I am ${obj.age} years old and I am a ${obj.job}`;
}

let result = createSentence(obj)

console.log(result);
```

Simple way. Don't wanna dive too deep but your main mistakes were:

1. Trying to reassign a value to const variables (this is not allowed)
2. Not referring to the passed argument (obj) but only to its keys. You either need to refer to them as obj.*key* or [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) them first.
3. You are trying to console.log(*result*), which is NOT a global variable. You first need to store the result of your function in a variable (called "result" in my example) to log it, or log the function-call itself. IE: console.log(createSentence(obj))

Answer (score 1):

Object destructuring is your friend... but there are other problems with your code.

You are attempting to reassign a constant. You also are not calling the function.

```
let obj = { name: 'Mitch', age: 29, job: 'tutor' };

function createSentence({ name, age, job }) { // return a string from obj    
    const result = `Hello my name is ${name}, I am ${age} years old and I am a ${job}`;
    return result;
}
console.log(createSentence(obj));
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You cant change `const` variable so change it to `let`
2. Using result variable twice is redundant.
3. You have to get properties from object with `.` notation

This is working:

```
let obj = { name: 'Mitch', age: 29, job: 'tutor' };
function createSentence(obj) { // return a string from obj    
    let result = `Hello my name is ${obj.name}, I am ${obj.age} years old and I am a ${obj.job}`;
    return result;
}
console.log(createSentence(obj));
```